# VBScript fails when sending left mouse click

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I am trying to develop script to open thinkorswim app (stock/option trading software) so that I can use that script inside my W10Pro pc Task Scheduler app to automatically open this app at specified time each day.  When opening the app via desktop shortcut, the app displays a login window, requiring username and password. Within this login window, left mouse click into the username field to activate it and input the info, tab to the password field to activate it and input the info, then tab, tab to the "login"  button, and press enter.

Script I am using is below. It keeps failing at line 6 when trying to send the left mouse click.

I have other scripts (such as opening a specific Excel file, opening notepad, running numerous macros on recurring basis each day, etc) which work successfully within Task Scheduler, so this is particularly frustrating.

Primary question - asking for any input or suggestions regarding the script.

I believe my screen coordinates for the mouse click "sendkeys" are correct but they were determined without the use of a coordinates software.  Secondary question - Can anyone recommend some good "freeware" so that I can double check the accuracy of my coordinates?

Thanks.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 1000 
WshShell.Run Chr(34) + "C:\Users\Tom Henry\AppData\Local\thinkorswim\thinkorswim.exe" + Chr(34)
WScript.Sleep 15000 
WshShell.AppActivate "thinkorswim"
WshShell.SendKeys "{CLICK LEFT,644,221}"
WScript.Sleep 1000 
WshShell.SendKeys "myusername"
WScript.Sleep 1000 
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "mypassword"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: In the (distant) past I'd use AutoIt for this kind of stuff.

Comment: You can't mouse click with sendkeys. You found code from a program not windows.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Excel, x, y
Set Excel = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
x = "644"
y = "221"
Excel.ExecuteExcel4Macro ( _
    "CALL(""user32"",""SetCursorPos"",""JJJ""," & x & "," & y & ")")
' Left Click
    Excel.ExecuteExcel4Macro("CALL(""User32"",""mouse_event"",""JJJJJJ""," & "2" & ")")
    Excel.ExecuteExcel4Macro("CALL(""User32"",""mouse_event"",""JJJJJJ""," & "4" & ")")
```

And, in browser(if you need specific coordinates but don't want to download any sketchy programs), move your mouse about where you'd like your coordinates to be. Press ctrl + shift + J, then paste this code in:

```
onmousemove = function(e){console.log("mouse location:", e.clientX, e.clientY)}
```

And press enter. Then, slightly move your mouse. Then, you'll get estimate coordinates!

Note: It may not be exact. So if it's off, adjust x and y in the VBScript code.

Enjoy! <3